# differentiating between "creation" and "creating"

Tags: gerunds

Could you please help me with the following sentence?

***Creating*** social projects/ ***creation*** of social projects is one of the efficient methods to monitor investments.

Would you please show me which one could be correct? and what is the difference between them?

Thanks
..........

***UPDATE***:
Could you think of a sample where the following could be interchangeable?

creation and creating

I have provided a sentence in which I think it works:

The committee recommended the creation of a new government agency to be responsible for the environment.

Excerpted from thesaurus Oxford

Comment: Grammatically both are correct.

Comment: A third way to say it is, "Social project creation is one of the efficient methods..."

Answer (score 2):

The latter part of your sentence is

> ... is one of the efficient methods to monitor investments.

*Creating* is a noun that means an instance of an activity of creating.

*Creation* would be something that has been created.

Google gives the following definition of *method*:

> a particular form of procedure for accomplishing or approaching
>   something, especially a systematic or established one.

Thus, *creating* is what you want to use, since it describes the manner or way something is accomplished/approached rather than the results of it.

Comment: More specifically, _creating_ is a gerund.